# Accessing a public dictionary in a class

Tags: excel, vba

Here is a basic class:

```
Public MyData As Dictionary

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set MyData = New Dictionary
End Sub
```

It's impossible to access the public dictionary:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim myClass As New cMyClass
    myClass.MyData("A") = 1
    Debug.Print myClass.MyData("A")
End Sub
```

Error:

```
Compile error: Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment
```

I guess this is related to the fact we can't have a public array in a class.

And that the root cause is the fact VBA offers **indexed properties** so in expression `myClass.MyData` VBA considers that `MyData` can only be an **indexed property** and won't search for anything else like a public dictionary.

Following this path I can indeed write:

```
Private pMyData As Dictionary

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set pMyData = New Dictionary
End Sub

Public Property Get MyData(key As String) As Variant
    MyData = pMyData(key)
End Property

Public Property Let MyData(key As String, value As Variant)
    pMyData(key) = value
End Property
```

And my `Test` sample above is working fine.

Do you confirm the origins of this limitation?

Is there another way?
I've tried `(myClass.MyData)("A") = 1` but it fails too with a `Syntax error`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, let's be clear.  In your example code, `MyData` is not a property, it's a *field*. If it were a property, it would need to be declared like this:

```
Private memberData As Dictionary

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set memberData = New Dictionary
End Sub

Public Property Get MyData() As Dictionary
    Set MyData = memberData
End Property
```

With that class declaration, your sample calling code works just fine:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim myClass As New cMyClass
    myClass.MyData("A") = 1
    Debug.Print myClass.MyData("A")
End Sub
```

What is obvious here is that VBA is either not exposing the public field `Public MyData As Dictionary` as a `Property Get` in the internal TypeInfo for the class, or declaring it as a field instead of a `propget` is confusing VBA's run-time binder.

Unfortunately I don't have access to tools for examining internal VBA TypeInfos ATM, but I can update this answer with more information when that's available...

Comment: Thanks, interesting that it's working fine with a property. And it's not at runtime: compiling the module will raise the error.

Comment: @Pragmateek Interesting. Should be the same root cause though. The static binding will still be using the same TypeInfo.

Answer (score 1):

since `myData` is a `Dictionary` object, you have to use `Dictionary` class methods to add elements to it

use:

```
myClass.MyData.Add "A", 1
```

hence:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim myClass As New cMyClass

    myClass.MyData.Add "A", 1

    Debug.Print myClass.MyData("A")
End Sub
```

Comment: Except that isn't true if the `Dictionary` isn't a class member. This works just fine: `Dim x As New Scripting.Dictionary: x("A") = 1` - In fact, the weird indexing behavior of `Dictionary` will "helpfully" add item `"A"` because it doesn't exist.

Comment: @Comintern, my answer is in the context of a Dictionary _being_ a class member. so I don't get neither your comment nor the down vote

Comment: The statement "you have to use Dictionary class methods to add elements" is incorrect. This doesn't have anything to do with adding members to a `Dictionary`. The root problem is that the `MyData.Item` indexer is never being called (as the OP points out in the question).

Comment: @DisplayName Thanks for you answer, but `Add` will complain if the element already exists. But indeed in the same manner I could do `myClass.MyData.Item("A") = 1` to get the same behavior.

Comment: @Comintern Indeed it's why I wanted to make my intention more obvious with `(myClass.MyData)("A") = 1` but it is not understood by VBA.

Comment: @Pragmateek All the parens around `(myClass.MyData)` do is force it from a `ByRef` call to a `ByVal` call. Since that is going to resolve to the same reference, it won't change the run-time binding behavior.

Comment: Indeed, I wanted to help VBA understand my intention, but it's not even compiling.

Comment: @Comintern, I once again tell you that my answer is to be read in the question background. OP wanted to use a "field" code instead of a "property" and I showed him how to do. May be I had to to choose word differently and just go _"to use Dictionary as a field you have to use Dictionary Add method"_ or the likes?

Comment: Huh? That's still wrong.  You don't have to call `.Add` to add an item to a `Dictionary`.

Comment: Seems like there's no way you can read the _entire_ text of my comments, while you keep extracting the pieces of it you need to endorse your first thesis and mantra. And the same applies to your backing comment upvoter, too. Suit yourself.

Comment: I downvoted your ***answer***, not your comments, and I explained why it is wrong. There is no "first thesis and mantra". The line "you have to use Dictionary class methods to add elements to it" is demonstratively false, as shown by the OP's code, the code in my answer, and [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee198743(v%3dtechnet.10)). You seem to also have missed the *OP's comment* that "Add will complain if the element already exists". I don't really care about that part, the downvote is purely for the attached misinformation.